# How do I write a C# analyzer that runs on diff code or newly added code only?

Tags: c#, diff, visual-studio-extensions, static-code-analysis

I have a certain number of C# projects. Some of them are cloned from TFS\AzureDevOps and some from Git. *For* these project, I'm writing a custom C# analyzer. Now I need to detect whether the rules I'm devising within the analyzer are being defied by newly added code or not. The idea is to run static code analysis on newly added code only. So basically, it's more of a static diff code analysis where the diff yields pending changes.

To keep it simple, when you create an analyzer project in visual studio, you get the following piece of code from where you can start:

```cs
// This method has been registered as a symbol action against 'SymbolKind.NamedType'
private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    var namedTypeSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)context.Symbol;

    // Find just those named type symbols with names containing lowercase letters.
    if (namedTypeSymbol.Name.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsLower))
    {
        // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
        var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, namedTypeSymbol.Locations[0], namedTypeSymbol.Name);

        // Report the diagnostic
        context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
    }
}
```

I need to do something like this:

```cs
// This method has been registered as a symbol action against 'SymbolKind.NamedType'
private static void AnalyzeSymbol(SymbolAnalysisContext context)
{
    // Before creating a diagnostic and reporting it, I want to detect
    // whether the symbol under question is from newly added code or not
    if (IsNewCode(context))
    {
        var namedTypeSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)context.Symbol;

        // Find just those named type symbols with names containing lowercase letters.
        if (namedTypeSymbol.Name.ToCharArray().Any(char.IsLower))
        {
            // For all such symbols, produce a diagnostic.
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, namedTypeSymbol.Locations[0], namedTypeSymbol.Name);

            // Report the diagnostic
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I implement the `IsNewCode()` method here?

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope for this site, which is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmers tool. Your quesiton is in no way specific. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this no matter what the technology is.  The problem is fundamentally that you can't analyze code fragments without knowing the surrounding context,   So if intend to look only at the diffs, I don't think you can do it.   If, however, you keep the old program around, and analyze the diffs using context taken from the old program, maybe you can do something.  But in essence you are doing whole-program analysis to process the diff lines.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thank you for your response. Second, I'm not aiming for complicated analysis requiring validating the codes semantics (semantic analysis). I'm merely looking for analyzing the syntax using very simple rules. For instance, triggering rule CA1305 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1305-specify-iformatprovider?view=vs-2019).